# Close Perpetually Unanswered Questions?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that a lot of simpler questions on AskUbuntu are answered in the comments rather than an actual answer, which leads to the question never being marked as answered. Should these be closed or ignored or other?

Comment: Examples would be good here. If the answer is solved in comments, ask the user who solved it to convert there comment to an answer so it is no longer unanswerd.

Comment: This one for example, as of 6am EST: http://askubuntu.com/questions/764201/note-taking-using-command-line-history

And I noticed after I answered it that this one had been answered in the comments: http://askubuntu.com/questions/764079/ubuntu-command-line-how-to-access-it/

Comment: The first one was answered, I guess through this question based on the timings and the second one that you answered is a duplicate, in the case of duplicates, the duplicate question is the answer, no need to answer those, they won't show as unanswered.